# Python TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I couldn't understand the other questions in Stackoverflow. When the circle moves towards the end of the screen, it moves towards the opposite direction.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,480])
screen.fill([255,255,255])
circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255,0,0],[100,100],30,0)
x = 50
y = 50
x_speed = 5
y_speed = 5

done = "False"
while done == "False":
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done="True"
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,[255,255,255],[x,y,30,30],0)
    x = x + x_speed
    y = y + y_speed
    if x > screen.get_width() - 30 or x < 0:
        x_speed = -x_speed
    if y > screen.get_height() - 30 or y < 0:
        y_speed = -y_speed
    screen.blit(circle,[x,y])
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

An error message is issued without being implemented.

> screen.blit(circle,[x,y]) 
>  
>   TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.draw.circle`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) returns a [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) not a [`pygame.Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and you can only `blit` surfaces not rects (that's what the traceback tells you). So create a surface object, use `pygame.draw.circle` to draw a circle onto it and then blit this surface onto the screen in your main loop.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,480])
screen.fill([255,255,255])

# A transparent surface with per-pixel alpha.
circle = pygame.Surface((60, 60), pygame.SRCALPHA)
# Draw a circle onto the `circle` surface.
pygame.draw.circle(circle, [255,0,0], [30, 30], 30)

x = 50
y = 50
x_speed = 5
y_speed = 5

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    pygame.time.delay(20)
    screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
    x = x + x_speed
    y = y + y_speed
    if x > screen.get_width() - 60 or x < 0:
        x_speed = -x_speed
    if y > screen.get_height() - 60 or y < 0:
        y_speed = -y_speed
    # Now blit the surface.
    screen.blit(circle, [x, y]) 
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: pygame.draw.circle(circle, [255,0,0], [30, 30], 30),  
If [30, 30] is increased, the colliding wall is not a window window.
It does not seem to be related to pygame surface ().
What's the problem? let me know the answer...

Comment: `if x > screen.get_width() - 30`, you have to change the 30 to 60 because that's the size of the circle in my example. I've edited the answer.